# Mac Mini with Dell UltraSharp U2713H - Not Sharp

Tags: display, mac-mini, resolution, hdmi

I have bought myself a 2012 Mac mini and have it hooked up to my Dell Ultrasharp U2713H via HDMI. Everything works, but the text and everything else looks fuzzy and not sharp.

Plus from what I can tell everything is blown up to be 2560 x 1440, and that makes stuff look large in size.

Why is this? and how can I fix it?

Comment: the screen resolution can be set by you.

Comment: look in to your display settings in sys pref for 2560 x 1440 at 60 Hz output, pending your graphic card support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Over HDMI that machine can only do 1920x1200.
Need Thunderbolt or MiniDP->DP or DVI to get 2560x1440 according to [EveryMac](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/mac_mini/specs/mac-mini-core-i5-2.5-late-2012-specs.html)

& those screens have more input options than you could ever need; I'd go miniDP to miniDP [or DP] as simplest solution.
That's what I use here on 2 of the same monitors - but I also double up with DVI-DVI on one screen, to toggle between 2 computers.

[image]

Comment: I'll do just that. Thank you. I have gone ahead and bought a miniDP to miniDP cable.